# Apache CXF JMX monitoring for SOAP clients

Tags: soap, jax-ws, cxf, jmx, java-metro-framework

According to http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jmx-management.html, CXF provides JMX monitoring for Web Service providers. The documentation is silent about whether it works for SOAP clients or not. Metro, on the other hand, clearly says that client monitoring is supported as well. The only reason I am looking at CXF is because it provides connection pooling which Metro does not, to my knowledge.
So my question really is, does anyone know if CXF supports client side JMX monitoring for SOAP clients? If yes, can you give some pointers? If not, is there a way to achieve connection pooling with Metro?

Comment: I deployed a JAX-WS service and a Spring controller client to Jetty and hit it with JConsole. I could see CXF MBeans but not any stats, even though I configured CounterRepository as per the CXF documentation. Until I find out otherwise, I'm inclined to believe that CXF does not support client side JMX monitoring and I've doubts whether it even supports server side stats as claimed in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, CXF does not support client side JMX monitoring. It has better support than Metro for server side monitoring, provided CounterRepository bean is configured.